# Eclipse (GGTS) "Computing Git status for repository [username]"

Tags: eclipse, egit

Each time I save an edit in Eclipse (GGTS/STS v3.4) it automatically runs the task: `Computing Git status for repository [username].`

The CPU usage rockets but it never seems to make any progress. I've left the process running for up to 15 minutes before giving up and stopping it manually. It then restarts the next time I save a change.

Presumably EGit is trying to synchronise but it isn't really clear what or why. Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Older versions of EGit used to automatically connect a project to its Git repository in case it finds a `.git` in any of the project's parent directories.

In your case, it seems you have a Git repository in your home directory. Depending on the size of your home directory, this can take a long time.

Since EGit 3.0.2, the home directory is no longer automatically indexed. So, make sure you are using EGit 3.0.2 or higher. In case you are using Eclipse 4.3.0, upgrade to 4.3.1. Otherwise upgrade to the newest version from the [EGit download page](http://eclipse.org/egit/download/).

After upgrading, open the *Git Repositories* view (using Ctrl+3 or Cmd+3 and typing its name). Then find the repository named [username] and remove it from the view.

Comment: Thanks robinst that seems to have fixed it. I'm using GGTS3.4 which seems to be built on top of Eclipse 4.3.1. When I created the project it did indeed create an entry for the repository in my home directory by default. Removing this repository from the view also removed my project from the project explorer, annoyingly, but it was easy to add this again and the project is behaving well!

Comment: Could you check the EGit version in *About Eclipse*?

Comment: It's using EGit 3.1.0.

Comment: same thing happens with EGit 3.4.0 in Eclipse Lunca (4.4)

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop this thread from running, try:
`rm -r .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/org.eclipse.egit.core`

and
`rm -r .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/.indexes/properties.index`

seems to be working! credit to http://willtipton.com/coding/2014/09/21/Eclipse-building-git-something.html

Answer (score 1):

Amir Dahan and Ryan Poolos's answer does work. Thanks a lot.
In Windows OS, you can open a "git bash" window if a git client was installed, then input the command.

If you just delete the "properties.index",they can be created again when you start the Eclipse next time.

Answer (score 0):

cleaning up org.eclipse.egit.core and properties.index was useful. It works for me to get rid of computing Git status issue.

But now I cannot sync my project.