# Eclipse “Computing Git status for repository Application”

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am using eclipse Kepler.
But Eclipse is always busy in "Computing Git status for repository Application" when something changed and it eats up my CPUs, and pops up a dialog.

I have to stop the dialog. Sometime later, it also pops up a same dialog. I try to  upgrade eclipse and search some solutions on stackoverflow. Unluckily, they are helpless.

How do I stop that? I’m fed up.

Comment: would http://stackoverflow.com/a/19466013/6309 help?